# User control page not getting created when building the website

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I am building the website I see all the files getting generated except the user control file usGridview.ascx.

So after building the website I manually copy this file and place it in the under the control called usercontrol, I am not sure what is causing the problem.

I am using VS 2008, C# as the platform

Answer (score 1):

What if you just build that user control, can you see any error in output window in Visual Studio?

Sometimes, if code of one user control is copied from another control, that mismatches file types either in .aspx page markup or code behind. Try following:

1) Make sure all the class names, master page types are correct

2) Try publishing the website instead of Building it.

3) Check the Build settings in Build --> Configuration Manager and make sure appropriate platform settings are selected.